# Call to undefined function Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть функции внутри плагина(save,get_data,get_image). В файл категория.пхп вставляю  шорткодом функцию get data и внутри этой функции вызывается get_image, но пишет , что Call to undefined function Wordpress get_image.

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/268581

Comment: увы там нету ответа на мой вопрос